# How can I loop through a folder containing inputfiles and write outputfiles in a different folder?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that is supposed to loop through a directory (source-folder) and run a program (myProgram) with all files in the directory and write the output to another directory. The files in output are supposed to have a slightly different name.

My myProgram takes 5 parameters:

```
 ./myProgram   PAR1   infile1.txt   PAR3  PAR4   infile_run1.txt
```

**source-folder:**

- infile1.txt
- infile2.txt
- infile3.txt

**dest-folder**

- infile_run1.txt
- infile_run2.txt
- infile_run3.txt

I can loop through the folder, run my program with all files but my problem is writing the output files into a different directory: Using my code below creates just 1 File named NewName.

How do I get an output file (to the dest-folder) for each input file (from the source-folder)?

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in  ~/path/to/source-folder/*;    
do    
    echo  $filename      
    ./myProgram -A $filename -B -C ~/path/to/dest-folder/Newname       
done
```

Comment: Is the last argument to `myProgram` the output file? Can you not just use a variable to set an output file based on the input file?

Comment: Yes last argument is the output. I am totally new to bash and do not know how to do that

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/use-command-line-arguments-in-bash-script, and many other tutorials on bash arguments.

Comment: quick and dirty you can use  something like /path/to/dest-folder/$(basename $filename) to get the base filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unsure about the features and options of *myProgram*, so just as a showcase, I created a file called *myProgram.sh*. Its purpose is to calculate the number of characters in each file and record the counts in the output files:

```
#!/bin/bash

src="./source-folder"
dest="./dest-folder"

for input in "$src"/infile*.txt;
do
    echo "Processing: $input"
    
    # Determine the base name
    base=$(basename "$input" .txt)
    
    # Construct the output filename
    output="$dest/${base}_run1.txt"
    
    # Call myProgram to count characters in the input file and capture the output
    char_count=$(./myProgram.sh "$input")
    
    # Write the character count to the output file
    echo "Character count: $char_count" > "$output"
done
```

And the *myProgram.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Count the number of characters in the input file
char_count=$(wc -c < "$1")
echo "$char_count"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for filename in  ~/path/to/source-folder/*; do
    ./myProgram -A $filename -B -C ~/path/to/dest-folder/$(basename $filename)
done
```

is probably how i would do it though I did not test it, but it should give you something to start on